# Permanent redirect from http to https page

Tags: .htaccess

When I try to create rules for redirect from HTTP pages to HTTPS pages (only for specific pages) with .htaccess, I've received loop redirect. Where am I wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/doctor) [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/client)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/doctor) [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/client)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found answer to my question:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/(client/|doctor/))
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/(client/|doctor/))
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 15):

to force https for a particular folder use

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} somefolder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/somefolder/$1 [R,L]
```

for entire site use

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

for specific pages you could use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/doctor/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Check if server port is different from 443 (standard for secure connections), to ensure we are going to redirect only non-secured connections

Redirect the page secure.php to secure domain, sending 301 response status, appending all query string and marking is as last rule, so any rules below this will not be parsed (since this is redirect, we don't want to take any other actions)

here is a solution without using .htaccess i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837657/https-only-on-specific-page-with-htaccess)

```
    <?php

//assuming you site structure like www.domain.com/p=doctor

    $redirectlist = array('doctor','nurse','anyother');

    if (in_array($_GET['p'], $redirectlist) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {
        exit(header("location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"));
    }

?>
```

Comment: I see, but I've problem when I want to show all pages, which don't located under /doctor and /client without https.

Comment: Don't use the SERVER_PORT variable, use HTTPS instead, that way if the listening port changes (or you listen on multiple ports), the redirect still works.

Comment: Use the [NE] flag so that reserved characters in the URL are not re-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/doctor/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/client/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If https is not on, and you are accessing /doctor or /client (or any sub-folders of those two), it should forward to HTTPS.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you replacing your two sets of rewriterules with this single set?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I've copied this text in my .htaccess, but I haven't redirect to https pages.

Comment: Ok, make sure you still have the RewriteEngine on statement, and that you have removed your existing HTTPS rules.  Are you accessing /doctor directly, or a page within that folder?

Comment: @Kazar: First of all - many thanks for your help. Yes, I've copied all the text in my .htaccess file again. But, I haven't found any changes. It doesn't work. I've access to the page by next URL for example: http://www.domainname.org/doctor/home.php

Comment: Is your main server configurations set up to allow rewrite rules in .htaccess files?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Kazar's answer, but more concise.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule !/(doctor|client)(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It is more concise, but if you ever need to add new pages to force to HTTPS, then you are going to have to modify that regex, rather than add a RewriteCond.  You start getting 20 or so secure pages and that regex is going to get pretty long.