# Redirection http to https and non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am using this code for SSL migration:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem that I am facing is that it is working is that the redirection is not working for most of the folders and URLs but in a few cases it is working and that is what is baffling me.

If the code was correct, it should work for every URL on the site instead of a few or it shouldn't work at all. When I remove the first re-write condition in the .htaccess, the site works just fine.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
https/www.mysite.com:443/some-folder/xyz.html
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to what I see, are your rules correct. According to a RewriteRule tester (http://htaccess.mwl.be) this is also the case. I don't think that these 4 lines are the problem...

Comment: But I face problem to find error why it is redirecting to wrong url @Blaatpraat

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am using your code but it is not working same error as define above @user1844933

Comment: @SandeepVishwakarma check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933045/1844933