# Reload page without ssl (https to http)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a secured site using ssl. I have a php file that checks the login and if you are not logged in it brings up a login form, once you log in the page refreshed and the login is checked again and when it passes it loads the page content. What i am trying to do is have it load the login in https then when the javascript gets the ok from ajax that the login was successful, the page is reloaded with just http to reduce the load time and latency of the page (these are large pages and any little thing will help). I need to do this dynamically, so i can not just give it a redirect url.

Comment: A simple 302 with a location header isn't working?  Is there an actual problem?  Are your users getting prompted that they are being redirected to an insecure site?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean but i need something that will take `https://blablabla.com/this.php` and reload it to `http://blablabla.com/this.php`

Comment: `header('Location: http://blablabla.com/this.php');`  However, I think if you go this route, IE users will tend to be notified that they are "being redirected to an insecure location".  It's been awhile since I've looked at this problem, but I believe if you just redirect with JavaScript, you don't have this issue.  However, you state in your question that you don't want to do this, but then tag it as JS/jQuery, so I'm not sure what you're asking really.

Comment: but i need to do this dynamically so it is integrated with the login. So if the person logins in on page `https://blablabla.com/this.php` they go to `http://blablabla.com/this.php` but if prompted to log in on `https://blablabla.com/other.php` they get redirected to `http://blablabla.com/this.php`

Comment: Is your question on how to parse the URL and re-assemble it with a protocol change?  Where are you doing your redirect?  JS or PHP?  Is your question on how to get the URL in the first place?

Comment: my question is on any way to do this, i am not sure how to start. I would rather not parse the url, but was hoping there was some kind of javascript work around for something this simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use this untested psuedo code loaded at the top of every page you require   a login on.

```
if(loggedin()&&$_SERVER[SERVER_PORT]==443)
{ 
   //if user is logged in but they are still on the https site, redirect to the http site
    header("Location:http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]");
}
elseif(!loggedin()&&$_SERVER[SERVER_PORT]!=443)
{
    //if the user is not logged in and they are not on the secure site,  send them to the login page on the secure site
    header("Location:https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/login.php");
}
```

Comment: i would like to do this in javascript as i need the user to be able to login on the page they are going to so not to a specific login page.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess usage is the recommended way to do this. Use .htaccess to use https only for a single page or specific pages.

Check this for more
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?694107-htaccess-rule-redirect-https-for-just-one-page

[HTTPS only on specific page with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837657/https-only-on-specific-page-with-htaccess)